# Calculating average of each line using apache pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, average

I'm writing a pig script that is supposed to calculate average of a each line.
The input is like this :

```
  (11, 10)
  (12, 108)
  (14, 106)
  (40, 101)
  (96, 104)
  (112, 410)
```

And i want to calculate the average of each row like this

```
average(11,10)
average(12,108)
average(14,106)
average(40,101)
...
```

how can i do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To calculate average, Pig has a built in function called AVG. AVG takes a bag as a parameter, so you need to create a bag out of you values. This can be done with script below.

The script below does not mind if you more than two values in one row, so you can change A to you liking.

```
A = LOAD 'data.txt' AS (a:int, b:int);
B = FOREACH A GENERATE TOBAG($0..) AS values;
C = FOREACH B GENERATE AVG(values);
```

Comment: You don't have to have two separate `FOREACH`s here, `B = FOREACH A GENERATE AVG(TOBAG($0..)) AS averaged ;` will also work.

Comment: Yes, that's probably more elegant solution.